# Why do I have this text "undefined" in my html file after I execute some javascript in script tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I am executing some java script in an if/else block that prints some tags/content to the html file using document.write() function. This piece of javascript is within the "script" tag just before I end the "body" tag. But I see a very weird behaviour: when my if() condition satisfies, I see some extra text "undefined" in the html. I am not writing this undefined text using JS. At the same time when the code within else {} block gets executed, this undefined text does not appear anymore in my html file. The strcture of my code is as follows:

```
if(){}
else{
  if(){
    html_text += "<div><p>hello world</p></div>";
    document.write(html_text);
  } else {
    html_text += "<div><p>No hello world</p></div>";
    document.write(html_text);
  }
}
```

Comment: You never initialized `html_text`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think he just left out the condition because it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: Lets just assume that the if condition is satisfying. And Barmar, I have initialized html_text before accessing it.

Comment: Then please show how you initialized it, because given the code you posted, @barmar is right.

Comment: Barmar you are right. I only declared the variable but never initialized it. Thank you so much for the help. I can't believe I spent the last two hours figuring out why undefined was being printed. I would be glad to accept your answer.

Comment: There are probably hundreds of potential duplicate questions, it's not worth answering again. I'm just too tired to search for them.

Answer (score 3):

That is because you have never initialized the variable `html_text`.

```
<script>
  var html_text = "";
  // Other code
  html_text += "<div><p>hello world</p></div>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Do everything in right syntax and initial variable before concatenating.

```
<script>
var html_text = "";

if(your_condition){
     html_text += "<div><p>hello world</p></div>";
     document.write(html_text);
}
else 
{
     html_text += "<div><p>No hello world</p></div>";
     document.write(html_text);
}

</script>
```

Comment: While you're at it, you could move `document.write` out of the conditional.

Comment: Nice comment @FedericoklezCulloca